# TextInput in ContentScript unable to gain focus when using browserActions.onClicked.addListener

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Click extension browserAction using chrome.browserAction.onClicked
2. Content Script is loaded
3. Text input in the content script is not focused

   - Even with `autoFocus={true}` or `input.focus()` or `window.focus()`

This actually works in Chrome Canary build Version 76.0.3775.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit).

Not sure if there's a setting or configuration issue.

I've used `window.activeElement` which returns the correct DOM elements.

Furthermore, what's odd is if I click anywhere on the page there's a slight flicker of the text input caret. So it seems as if the input actually gets focused but it's not visible.

Comment: Without trying your extension myself all I can say it's either a problem in your code or in this site or it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Considering it works in the Canary build I believe it's a bug with Chrome.
It would seem the transfer (of focus) from click on the browerAction to the webpage does not occur.

Because when I log `document.hasFocus()` when content script is loaded. It returns`false` in the latest stable version of Chrome but in Canary build it returns `true`

Comment: I've posted this question in hopes of anyone having similar issues. Either there's a workaround of if this is simply the behavior with Chrome

Comment: I've yet to find any solutions. Not with any of the focus functions that I mentioned above

Comment: Extensions don't have any API to transfer focus between parts of browser UI.

Comment: Yeh I thought so, thanks. What's odd at this point is that it works on the canary build but not on the stable build. Any idea where I could investigate that. I'm not sure where to find fixed issues from Chromium

Comment: See https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to take a look at that tool